# NSPopover not showing content on macOS Sonoma

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm experiencing a weird issue where NSPopover doesn't show content. What's also strange is that when inspecting view in Xcode Debug View Hierarchy, it renders all the views as expected.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewa81.png)

Here is how the Xcode Debug View Hierarchy looks like:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL5a4.png)

I just don't understand the issue; why is LoginViewController's view not shown. This issue started with macOS Sonoma.

Here is the Popover setup:

```
{
    _popover = NSPopover.new;
    _popover.animates = NO;
    _popover.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorApplicationDefined;

    NSViewController* vc;
    if (user == nil)
    {
        vc = LoginViewController.new;
    }
    else
    {
        vc = MessageViewController.new;
    }
    _popover.contentViewController = [RootViewController.alloc initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [_popover.contentViewController loadView];
    _statusItem = [NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar statusItemWithLength:24];
    _statusItem.button.action = @selector(onPress);
    _statusItem.button.target = self;
    [self reloadPopoverTrayImageForce:YES];
}
```

And here is how Popover's RootViewController is setup. I mean nothing out-of-standard here, just embedding the child view controller and his view to parent's view controller.

```
{
    self.view = NSView.new;
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
    if (self.rootViewController)
    {
        [self addChildViewController:self.rootViewController];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
        self.rootViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        id r = @{ @"root": self.rootViewController.view };
        [self.containerView addFor:r constraints:@"|[root]|"];
        [self.containerView addFor:r constraints:@"V:|[root]|"];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.footerView];
    [self reloadConstraints];

    id v = @{
            @"container": self.containerView,
            @"footer": self.footerView
    };

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:WIDTH]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:HEIGHT]];

    [self.view addFor:v constraints:@"|[container]|"];
    [self.view addFor:v constraints:@"|[footer]|"];
    [self.view addFor:v constraints:@"V:|[container]-0-[footer(44)]|"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the macOS Sonoma AppKit has made changes to NSView's drawing behavior. Now view's drawing is not limited by its bounds.

When you add a view of your child controller, try to set `clipsToBounds = true`. By default on macOS Sonoma it is false.

Also try to set `clipsToBounds = true` for all your custom views.